# Spark/Scala repeated calls to withColumn() using the same function on multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I currently have code in which I repeatedly apply the same procedure to multiple DataFrame Columns via multiple chains of .withColumn, and am wanting to create a function to streamline the procedure.  In my case, I am finding cumulative sums over columns aggregated by keys:

```
val newDF = oldDF
  .withColumn("cumA", sum("A").over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("time")))
  .withColumn("cumB", sum("B").over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("time")))
  .withColumn("cumC", sum("C").over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("time")))
  //.withColumn(...)
```

What I would like is either something like:

```
def createCumulativeColums(cols: Array[String], df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  // Implement the above cumulative sums, partitioning, and ordering
}
```

or better yet:

```
def withColumns(cols: Array[String], df: DataFrame, f: function): DataFrame = {
  // Implement a udf/arbitrary function on all the specified columns
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `select` with varargs including `*`:

```
import spark.implicits._

df.select($"*" +: Seq("A", "B", "C").map(c => 
  sum(c).over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("time")).alias(s"cum$c")
): _*)
```

This:

- Maps columns names to window expressions with `Seq("A", ...).map(...)`
- Prepends all pre-existing columns with `$"*" +: ...`.
- Unpacks combined sequence with `... : _*`.

and can be generalized as:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame}

/**
 * @param cols a sequence of columns to transform
 * @param df an input DataFrame
 * @param f a function to be applied on each col in cols
 */
def withColumns(cols: Seq[String], df: DataFrame, f: String => Column) =
  df.select($"*" +: cols.map(c => f(c)): _*)
```

If you find `withColumn` syntax more readable you can use `foldLeft`:

```
Seq("A", "B", "C").foldLeft(df)((df, c) =>
  df.withColumn(s"cum$c",  sum(c).over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("time")))
)
```

which can be generalized for example to:

```
/**
 * @param cols a sequence of columns to transform
 * @param df an input DataFrame
 * @param f a function to be applied on each col in cols
 * @param name a function mapping from input to output name.
 */
def withColumns(cols: Seq[String], df: DataFrame, 
    f: String =>  Column, name: String => String = identity) =
  cols.foldLeft(df)((df, c) => df.withColumn(name(c), f(c)))
```

Comment: is there a way to apply a list of functions to those same columns dynamically? so if there are N columns  and M functions, there would be N*M new columns.

Comment: @jgaw Just use nested loop. Either `for {f <- func; c <- cols} yield f(c)` or `funs.flatMap(f => cols.map(c => f(c)))`

Answer (score 9):

The question is a bit old, but I thought it would be useful (perhaps for others) to note that folding over the list of columns using the `DataFrame` as accumulator and mapping over the `DataFrame` have substantially different performance outcomes when the number of columns is not trivial (see [here](https://lansalo.com/2018/05/13/spark-how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-dataframes-and-how-not-to/) for the full explanation).
Long story short... for few columns `foldLeft` is fine, otherwise `map` is better.

Comment: Is this still valid with Spark with 2.4?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 2):

In PySpark:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

window = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("time")

df.select(
    "*", # selects all existing columns
    *[
        F.sum(col).over(window).alias(col_name)
        for col, col_name in zip(["A", "B", "C"], ["cumA", "cumB", "cumC"])
    ]
)
```