# add columns in dataframes dynamically with column names as elements in List

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have List[N] like below

```
val check = List ("a","b","c","d")
```

where N can be any number of elements.

I have a `dataframe` with only column called "value". Based on the contents of value i need to create N columns with column names as elements in the list and column contents as `substring(x,y)`

I have tried all possible ways, like `withColumn`, `selectExpr`, nothing works.
Please consider `substring(X,Y)` where X and Y as some numbers based on some metadata

Below are my different codes which I tried, but none worked,

---

```
val df = sqlContext.read.text("xxxxx")
val coder: (String => String) = (arg: String) => {
val param = "NULL"
if (arg.length() > Y )
arg.substring(X,Y)
else
val sqlfunc = udf(coder)
val check = List ("a","b","c","d")
for (name <- check){val testDF2 = df.withColumn(name, sqlfunc(df("value")))}
```

testDF2 has only last column d and other columns such as a,b,c are not added in table

---

```
var z:Array[String] = new Array[String](check.size)
var i=0
for ( x <- check ) {
if ( (i+1) == check.size) {
z(i) = s""""substring(a.value,X,Y) as $x""""
i = i+1}
else{
z(i) = s""""substring(a.value,X,Y) as $x","""
i = i+1}}
val zz = z.mkString(" ")
df.alias("a").selectExpr(s"$zz").show()
```

This throws error

---

Please help how to add columns in DF dynamically with column names as elements in List

I am expecting an Df like below

```
-----------------------------
Value| a | b | c | d | .... N
-----------------------------
|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxxxxx-                
|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxxxxx- 
|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxx|xxxxxx-
-----------------------------
```

Comment: please format your question and show example data plus expected ouptut.

Comment: still unclear, what is in the original  `df`

Comment: just one column named **value** with some data in it @mtoto

Comment: then please share it, and again clean up your code. I tried to do it for you but its still a mess.

Answer (score 4):

you can dynamically add columns from your list using for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400504/spark-scala-repeated-calls-to-withcolumn-using-the-same-function-on-multiple-c) answer by user6910411 to a similar question (see her/his full answer for more possibilities):

`val newDF = check.foldLeft(<yourdf>)((df, name) => df.withColumn(name,<yourUDF>$"value"))`