# Spark dataframe pivot median per quarter

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a Spark dataframe calculating the median per quarter and then add additional columns to calculate the differences between two quarters

Sample data:

```
schema = "id INT, amount INT, timestmp STRING"

data = ((1,5000,"06.01.2020 00:39"), \
    (1,2340,"26.02.2020 12:35"), \
    (1,491,"01.03.2020 04:55"), \
    (1,7801,"09.04.2020 14:51"), \
    (1,2900,"19.05.2020 00:51"), \
    (1,1200,"29.06.2020 10:01"), \
    (1,890,"03.07.2020 12:31"), \
    (1,3201,"09.08.2020 01:07"), \
    (1,4449,"13.09.2020 17:01"), \
    (2,3945,"09.01.2020 00:39"), \
    (2,1846,"29.02.2020 12:35"), \
    (2,387,"04.03.2020 04:55"), \
    (2,6155,"12.04.2020 14:51"), \
    (2,3542,"22.05.2020 00:51"), \
    (2,947,"02.06.2020 10:01"), \
    (2,702,"06.07.2020 12:31"), \
    (2,1886,"12.08.2020 01:07"), \
    (2,3510,"16.09.2020 17:01"))

dfraw = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df = dfraw.withColumn("purch_date", to_date(col("timestmp"),'dd.MM.yyyy')).drop("timestmp")

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- purch_date: date (nullable = true)

+---+------+----------+
| id|amount|purch_date|
+---+------+----------+
|  1|  5000|2020-01-06|
|  1|  2340|2020-02-26|
|  1|   491|2020-03-01|
|  1|  7801|2020-04-09|
|  1|  2900|2020-05-19|
|  1|  1200|2020-06-29|
|  1|   890|2020-07-03|
|  1|  3201|2020-08-09|
|  1|  4449|2020-09-13|
|  2|  3945|2020-01-09|
|  2|  1846|2020-02-29|
|  2|   387|2020-03-04|
|  2|  6155|2020-04-12|
|  2|  3542|2020-05-22|
|  2|   947|2020-06-02|
|  2|   702|2020-07-06|
|  2|  1886|2020-08-12|
|  2|  3510|2020-09-16|
+---+------+----------+
```

The result should be something like this (order of columns may be different):

```
+---+--------------+-------+-------+--------------+-------+-------+--------------+
| id|median_2020-q1|q2-q1_s|q2-q1_p|median_2020-q2|q3-q2_s|q3-q2_p|median_2020-q3|
+---+--------------+-------+-------+--------------+-------+-------+--------------+
|  1|          2340|    560|   23.9|          2900|    301|   10.4|          3201|
|  2|          1846|   1696|   91.9|          3542|  -1656|  -46.8|          1886|
+---+--------------+-------+-------+--------------+-------+-------+--------------+
```

columns 2, 5 and 8 = median of "amount" per quarter

columns 3 and 6 = difference between median of two quarters

columns 4 and 7 = difference between two quarters in percent (e.g. q2-q1_p = q2-q1_s / median_2020-q1 * 100)

Highly appreciate any helpful suggestions how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculating the median, you can use [percentile_approx](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.percentile_approx.html) function. Here's how you can approach the problem

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
schema = "id INT, amount INT, timestmp STRING"


data = ((1,5000,"06.01.2020 00:39"), \
    (1,2340,"26.02.2020 12:35"), \
    (1,491,"01.03.2020 04:55"), \
    (1,7801,"09.04.2020 14:51"), \
    (1,2900,"19.05.2020 00:51"), \
    (1,1200,"29.06.2020 10:01"), \
    (1,890,"03.07.2020 12:31"), \
    (1,3201,"09.08.2020 01:07"), \
    (1,4449,"13.09.2020 17:01"), \
    (2,3945,"09.01.2020 00:39"), \
    (2,1846,"29.02.2020 12:35"), \
    (2,387,"04.03.2020 04:55"), \
    (2,6155,"12.04.2020 14:51"), \
    (2,3542,"22.05.2020 00:51"), \
    (2,947,"02.06.2020 10:01"), \
    (2,702,"06.07.2020 12:31"), \
    (2,1886,"12.08.2020 01:07"), \
    (2,3510,"16.09.2020 17:01"))

dfraw = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df = dfraw.withColumn("purch_date", F.to_date(F.col("timestmp"),'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm')).drop("timestmp")
df = df.withColumn('quarters',F.quarter(df.purch_date).cast('string')).drop("purch_date")


output = df.groupBy('id').pivot("quarters").agg(
    F.percentile_approx("amount", 0.5, F.lit(1000000)))


output = output.withColumn('q2-q1_s',F.col('2') - F.col('1')) \
.withColumn('q2-q1_p',F.round((F.col('2') - F.col('1'))/F.col('1')*100,1)) \
.withColumn('q3-q2_s',F.col('3') - F.col('2'))\
.withColumn('q3-q2_p',F.round((F.col('3') - F.col('2'))/F.col('2')*100,1))

output.show()
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
+---+----+----+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id|   1|   2|   3|q2-q1_s|q2-q1_p|q3-q2_s|q3-q2_p|
+---+----+----+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1|2340|2900|3201|    560|   23.9|    301|   10.4|
|  2|1846|3542|1886|   1696|   91.9|  -1656|  -46.8|
+---+----+----+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Note: You might want to look at this answer on [how to create multiple columns dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155079/creating-multiple-columns-in-spark-dataframe-dynamically)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution! I'm using Spark 3.0 (cannot upgrade as I'm not in charge of the infrastructure) and percentile_approx was introduced in 3.1. I tried to change it to use approxQuantile:
output = df.groupBy('id').pivot("quarters").agg(df.approxQuantile("amount", 0.5, F.lit(1000000)))
output = df.groupBy('id').pivot("quarters").agg(statFunc(df).approxQuantile("amount", [0.5], 0.25))
both versions fail => *AssertionError: all exprs should be Column*
Any suggestion to re-write it without percentile_approx?

Comment: Can you convert it to Pandas DF for the sake of transformations?

Comment: Converting to Pandas worked
df_pd = df.toPandas()  
df_pd_out = pd.pivot_table(df_pd, values='amount', index=['id'], columns=['quarters'], aggfunc=np.median)  
...  Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect! Note that wherever possible working with spark data frame and not converting back and forth often,  is more efficient, given the optimisations performed under hood. But given that you are bound by the version of spark, etc... converting to pandas might be better for such transformations.