# Spark window function on dataframe with large number of columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an ML dataframe which I read from csv files. It contains three types of columns:

> ID Timestamp Feature1 Feature2...Feature_n

where n is ~ 500 (500 features in ML parlance). The total number of rows in the dataset is ~ 160 millions.

As this is the result of a previous full join, there are many features which do not have values set.

My aim is to run a "fill" function(fillna style form python pandas), where each empty feature value gets set with the previously available value for that column, per Id and Date.

I am trying to achieve this with the following spark 2.2.1 code:

```
 val rawDataset = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv(inputLocation)

 val window = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("DATE").rowsBetween(-50000, -1)

 val columns = Array(...) //first 30 columns initially, just to see it working

val rawDataSetFilled = columns.foldLeft(rawDataset) { (originalDF, columnToFill) =>
      originalDF.withColumn(columnToFill, coalesce(col(columnToFill), last(col(columnToFill), ignoreNulls = true).over(window)))
    }
```

I am running this job on a 4 m4.large instances on Amazon EMR, with spark 2.2.1. and dynamic allocation enabled.

The job runs for over 2h without completing.

Am I doing something wrong, at the code level? Given the size of the data, and the instances, I would assume it should finish in a reasonable amount of time? And I haven't even tried with the full 500 columns, just with about 30!

Looking in the container logs, all I see are many logs like this:

> INFO codegen.CodeGenerator: Code generated in 166.677493 ms
>
> INFO execution.ExternalAppendOnlyUnsafeRowArray: Reached spill
>   threshold of
>   4096 rows, switching to
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter

I have tried setting parameter **spark.sql.windowExec.buffer.spill.threshold** to something larger, without any impact. Is theresome other setting I should know about? Those 2 lines are the only ones I see in any container log.

In Ganglia, I see most of the CPU cores peaking around full usage, but the memory usage is lower than the maximum available. All executors are allocated and are doing work.

Comment: Did you look at the execution plan? If your dataframe is not repartitioned by ID and sorted in partitions by Id and DATE there will be a shuffle and sort before foldLeft. Could this be the reason? Also, is the limit really -50000 necessary? Maybe you should try first with some smaller values like -10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have managed to rewrite the **fold left** logic without using **withColumn** calls. Apparently they can be **very slow** for large number of columns, and I was also getting stackoverflow errors because of that.

I would be curious to know why this massive difference - and what exactly happens behind the scenes with the query plan execution, which makes repeated **withColumns** calls so slow.

Links which proved very helpful: [Spark Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7276) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400504/spark-scala-repeated-calls-to-withcolumn-using-the-same-function-on-multiple-c)

```
    var rawDataset = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv(inputLocation)    
    val window = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("DATE").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    rawDataset = rawDataset.select(rawDataset.columns.map(column => coalesce(col(column), last(col(column), ignoreNulls = true).over(window)).alias(column)): _*)
    rawDataset.write.option("header", "true").csv(outputLocation)
```

Comment: Nice solution. How fast is it now?

Comment: You can see a very nice blog post about this [here](https://lansalo.com/2018/05/13/spark-how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-dataframes-and-how-not-to) where you also get a nice benchmark.