# Alternative to the use of the 'withColumn' function in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reviewing the code of a development and I need to avoid or use a different way of adding columns with the use of the 'withColumn' function in a dataframe; but I have the following doubts:

1. Using nested 'withColumn', create new tables (as the code below)? using 6 'withColumn', create 6 new in memory tables?

```scala
newDataframe = table
.withColumn("name", col("consolidate").cast(DecimalType(17,2)))
.withColumn("name", col("consolidate").cast(DecimalType(17,2)))
```

2. If the use of many 'withColumn' increases memory usage and lowers performance (if true), how can I avoid using 'withColumn' when adding columns in a dataframe and get the same result?
3. Is there a way that consumes less memory and is faster to run without using 'withColumn', but getting the same result ?, that is, a dataframe with 6 columns added

I don't know how to do this.

The code to optimize is like this:

```
def myMethod(table: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    newDataframe = table
      .withColumn("name", col("consolidate").cast(DecimalType(17,2)))
      .withColumn("id_value", col("east").cast(DecimalType(17,2)))
      .withColumn("x_value", col("daily").cast(DecimalType(17,2)))
      .withColumn("amount", col("paid").cast(DecimalType(17,2)))
      .withColumn("client", col("lima").cast(DecimalType(17,2)))
      .withColumn("capital", col("econo").cast(DecimalType(17,2)))
    newDataframe
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark/Scala repeated calls to withColumn() using the same function on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400504/spark-scala-repeated-calls-to-withcolumn-using-the-same-function-on-multiple-c)

Comment: The answer provided is correct, but here is something that you can allude to foldLeft with withColumn that could well be the issue you mean: https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015

Answer (score 0):

There is a misconception here : Spark does not create the 6 intermediary datasets in memory. In fact your function won't trigger any change in memory as Spark transformations (such as `withColumn`) are evaluated lazily only when a action is called (such as `.count()` or `.show()`).

When the action is called Spark will optimize your transformations and do them all at once, so there is no problem with calling 6 times `.withColumn` in term of memory.

Comment: This is true. Also wanted to point out that every `.withColumn` call creates a new dataframe object in the driver's memory since `DataFrame` is immutable. So calling a thousand `.withColumn` will show a spike in the driver heap memory until GC. This is due to object creation and not data read.

Comment: @Gsquare  This is how I understood it, but I was doing some testing on select vs withColumn / foldLeft and could not see any time difference and thus no real performance difference. I tried under 2.4 crappy community databricks, fine. 2.2 did not show results but jobs on UI fine. Can you comment here?

Comment: @Fabich  Can you comment?

Comment: @thebluephantom there won't be any performance difference. Just saying that `.select(thousandColumnNames.map(col(_)):_*)` is easier on driver memory over `thousandColumnNames.foldLeft(df){(dataFrame, colName) => dataFrame.withColumn(colName, col(colName)}` as it creates fewer dataframe objects. Negligible difference maybe.

Comment: I have read a couple of articles. E.g. https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015 & https://lansalo.com/2018/05/13/spark-how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-dataframes-and-how-not-to/  They seem good sources. the 2nd one more so. @Gsquare   Who to believe? spinning up a cluster emr to check in a few days.

Comment: I just setup a test on Databricks community cluster as well:
`
val columns = 1 to 100000

import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.range(100000)

val df2 = df.select(columns.map(c => col("id").alias(s"column_{c}")):_*)

val df3 = columns.foldLeft(df.toDF) { case (dataFrame, ind) => dataFrame.withColumn(s"column_{ind}", col("id"))}
`

Comment: The `df2` evaluated in about 10 seconds whereas `df3` has been running for over 10 minutes now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205009/discussion-between-gsquare-and-thebluephantom).

Comment: s"column_{$c}"  is what you meant.

Comment: I have to be honest, I generated some data and found that the performance difference on community databricks even - was not that differing using withColumn compared to select... May be things have gotten a lot better, with 2,4.