# Repeated calls to withColumn() using the same function on multiple columns in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in which I repeatedly apply the same procedure to multiple columns via multiple chains of .withColumn, like this

```
   df=     dt.withColumn('PL_start', from_unixtime('PL_start', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) \
            .withColumn('PL_end??'  , from_unixtime('PL_end', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))   \
            .withColumn('MU_start', from_unixtime('MU_start', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) \
            .withColumn('MU_end'  , from_unixtime('MU_end', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))   \
            .withColumn('PU_start', from_unixtime('PU_start', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) \
            .withColumn('PU_end'  , from_unixtime('PU_end', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))   \
            .withColumn('RE_start', from_unixtime('RE_start', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) \
            .withColumn('RE_end'  , from_unixtime('RE_end', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))   \
            .withColumn(...)
```

I found this [repeated calls to withColumn() using the same function on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400504/spark-scala-repeated-calls-to-withcolumn-using-the-same-function-on-multiple-c) The question is a bit old. Wondering if there is a workaround for this in new version Spark, 2.4.3?

Comment: try `cols=['MU_end','PU_start','PU_end','RE_start']`
`dt.select(*[from_unixtime(x).alias(x) for x in cols])`

Comment: if u want all other columns with all new changed ones, `cols=['MU_end','PU_start','PU_end','RE_start']`
 `dt.select(*[x for x in dt.columns if x not in cols],*[from_unixtime(x).alias(x) for x in cols]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use python reduce function to iterate through columns:

```
new_df = (reduce(
lambda memo_df, col_name: memo_df.withColumn(col_name, from_unixtime(col(col_name), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")),
df.columns,
df))
```

If your df have some columns that you don't need to convert - replace df.columns with the sequence of columns you need.